# Getting an "operation not supported" error when trying to RUN something while building a docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker image with the following command:

```
docker build -f conf/Dockerfile -t my_app_name .
```

The `Dockerfile` starts with:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

COPY conf/pubkey pubkey
RUN echo 'deb http://downloads.skewed.de/apt/trusty trusty universe' >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && apt-key add pubkey \
  && rm pubkey
```

And it returns `INFO[0000] operation not supported`.

Regardless of what I put after RUN (even `RUN echo 1` fails)

I tried running a shell in the intermediate docker image (`docker run a7bb092… -it /bin/sh`) but this just throws `FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container a7bb092…: operation not supported`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, turns out that if your machine had a kernel update but you didn't restart yet then docker freaks out. Restarting the machine fixed that. Oops.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you do not have CONFIG_VETH selected in your kernel or don't have lxc and cgroup.

```
$ zcat /proc/config.gz | grep VETH
CONFIG_VETH=m
```

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7246